# Not allowed to board in connecting flight by saying that visa document is invalid

Tags: visas, canada, lhr, denied-boarding

I boarded from New Delhi to Toronto with halt at London with same airlines.. After inspecting my relevant documents,The airlines issued me Boarding pass from New Delhi to London by saying that next boarding pass would be issued to you at Heathrow Airport because an error is showing here in our system.

When i reached at airlines counter to get my boarding pass from London to Toronto then they told me that our system is showing that your visa document is invalid, hence we can't issue boarding pass to you for final destination. Accordingly, i come back to my country with no other option.

It is totally negligence & carelessness of airways who has not told at intial stage regarding this fact. Now, what action can i take against the airlines for physical, mental,social & legal harassment & humiliation?

Comment: Was the visa invalid?

Comment: I understand that being denied boarding isn't a pleasant experience, but which part of it do you think constitutes "physical, mental,social & legal harassment & humiliation"?

Comment: @ChrisH who knows what treatment did the OP receive when they were stuck at the airport on the stopover

Comment: @HankyPanky one would assume OP does. But they surely can't expect to receive advice as to what action they can take without explaining *why* they'd be taking that action.

Comment: @Ram Krishan Did you ask what kind of error was showing? That type of comment seems like a big red flag and would have worried me enough to make me want to make sure I understood what the problem was

Comment: "What action can i take" - Ram, the only thing you can do is have a solicitor look in to the matter.  If they feel they can take action, they will.

Answer (score 2):

The visa is the responsibility of traveller. Airlines can be fined if they allowed anyone to travel without valid visa. They apparently made a mistake when checking for Visa from India.

When they found that the visa is invalid, they rightfully rejected boarding and probably sent you back to the origin. It is the usual procedure. You don't have any recourse other than a return ticket to your home country (which airline can or cannot charge for latter, according to the conditions of carriage).

In other hand, the visa was actually valid and airline authority made a mistake, then you can raise a complaint.

Comment: If the airline thought the visa was invalid, why did they let the passenger board on the first port?

Comment: Apparently the gate agent in India allowed the person to board without checking validity of visa. That's a costly mistake on gate agent's part.

Comment: "Apparently the gate agent in India allowed the person to board without checking validity of visa": this may be true, but the statement in the question "that next boarding pass would be issued to you at Heathrow Airport because an error is showing here in our system" suggests that it may not be.  Are you suggesting that they had some sort of red flag that had nothing to do with the visa?  In my experience (granted, not with Indian airlines or Indian ground staff), visas for all transit points and the final destination are checked during the initial checkin.

Comment: Canada also has APIS so it could have been because there was a problem with APIS at that time. Or it could have been that the check-in agent misinterpreted the "error" and should have denied boarding rather than issuing a boarding pass for the first segment.